# Android - White background color, Automatically change to another color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I created an android application. And dashboard layout have multiple fragment and background color is white.

In some places i am using custom colors. Sometimes that white background color, automatically change to my customize color. For an Ex:Background change White to Orange.

Is there any solution....

Comment: it wont automatically change. there's gotta be something wrong.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Did you mentioned the background color in your layout? Or by default it visible in white color?

Comment: Try to define this background in fragment xml instead of activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems with colours. Sometimes worked just fine and sometimes the colour of random views was changed. It is some kind of leakage (didn't have time to search for it) and as a workaround I changed problematic colours to rectangle drawables like this, and this strange behaviour stopped:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've fixed it the same, but goes here to find more accurate solution, and so surprised that nobody have the same problem. Seems that is no many who need to change the background dynamically.